# Cross vCenter vMotion to linked vCenter

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli, vcenter

Configuration

We have two vcenters that are linked and we can vMotion no problem using the GUI - but when using PowerCLI we run into issues in getting the system to migrate.

### Vcenters

- vcsa1
- vcsa2

### VM Name

- test-vm

The Storage and the Network are named the same on both systems

- IE Storage named: company_storage (Both on vcsa1 and vcsa2)
- the esxi hosts are different, but we have a Linux, Windows cluster configured on each of the vcsa's
- the Network is a distributed Switch with matching names on both vcsa's as well

Note: our names have pipes in them - for example COMPANY|ACI|VLAN###

Here is the code I am using and have been trying to modify (From Example 11 in the Link above)

```
$vc1 = 'vcsa1.company.com'
$vc2 = 'vccs2.company.com'
$MyVm = 'test-vm'
$cred = Get-Credential


### Connect to dc1-vcsa and dc2-vcsa
Connect-VIServer $vc1 -Credential $cred
Connect-VIServer $vc2 -Credential $cred

## Get VAriables from output after connecting to VCSAs
$vm = Get-VM $MyVm
$destinationCluster = Get-VM $MyVm | Get-Cluster | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# Get destination datastore accessible to both vCenter Servers
$destinationDatastore = "pure_vm_prod"

# Get destination port group name or key
$PG =  Get-VirtualPortGroup -VM $MyVm
$destinationPortGroup = "'(Get-VirtualPortGroup -VM $MyVm).Name'"

## Command to initiate Migration from DC1 to DC2
Move-VM -VM $vm -DestinationType Datastore -Datastore $destinationDatastore -PortGroup $destinationPortGroup -Server $vc2 -Credential $cred
```

When I echo out the variables it gives me the data, but returns the following error:

```
     | "'(Get-VirtualPortGroup -VM test-migration).Name'" value of type
     | "System.String" to type
     | "VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Types.V1.Host.Networking.VirtualPortGroupBase".
```

I have tried several variations on this data - converting to string, escaping the output of the pipe characters, manually entering the correct name, adding the following example code to several of the variables:

```
"(Get-VirtualPortGroup -VM $MyVm).Name"
```

Comment: Use this instead: `$destinationPortGroup = Get-VirtualPortGroup -VM $MyVm`. Also the `-Datastore` parameter requires a [`SrorageResource`](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/structures/vmware.vimautomation.vicore.types.v1.datastoremanagement.storageresource/) object, so you might need to run `Get-Datastore` to get the datastore object like you did with port group instead of just the datastore name. See the [`Move-VM` documentation](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/commands/move-vm/#Default)

Comment: That seemed to fix my issue with that - now getting another error - will take a look at that.